# Read multidimensional array with Condition using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array as follows,

```
array('Hundai'=>array('Sonata','i20','Santro','Verna'),'Suzuki'=>array('Alto','Ritz'),'WW'=>array('Polo','Passat','Vento'))
```

I would like to retrieve only

*Sonata, i20, Santro and Verna*

when *Hundai* is my  input. Anybody suggest me solution with minimum number of loop

Comment: What's wrong with `print_r($cars['Hundai'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
  'Hyundai' => array('Sonata', 'i20', 'Santro', 'Verna'),
  'Suzuki' => array('Alto', 'Ritz'),
  'VW' => array('Polo', 'Passat', 'Vento')
);

$key = 'Hyundai';

if (isset($arr[$key]) && is_array($arr[$key])) {
  echo implode(', ', $arr[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var_dump($array['Hundai']);
```

Or

`echo implode(',', $array['Hundai']);`

or

```
foreach($array['Hundai'] as $value){
   eacho $value.' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($main_array as $key=>$value)
{
if($key=='Hyundai')
{
print_R($value);
}
}
```

then depends how you want to retrieve .. you can return the whole $value array or select certain part of it...

Answer (score 0):

Given that you name your array something like `$cars` and `$brand` is your input.

```
print_r($cars[$brand]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will take the last two elements of the array and merge them into one with the word `and` between. Then it will implode the array with `,` as separator.

```
$item = $array['Hundai'];
$count = count($item);
if($count > 1) {
  $end = $item[$count-2] .' and '.$item[$count-1];
  $item = array_slice($item, 0, $count-2);
  $item[] = $end;
}
$string = implode(', ', $item);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's with all those foreach loops, you don't need one?

```
$cars = array(
    'Hundai' => array(
        'Sonata',
        'i20',
        'Santro',
        'Verna'
    ),
    'Suzuki' => array(
        'Alto',
        'Ritz'
    ),
    'VW' => array(
        'Polo',
        'Passat',
        'Vento'
    )
);

$car = 'Hundai';

echo implode( ', ', $cars[$car] );
```